# UITableViewのDelegateを拡張する方法

Tags: swift, ios

UITableViewを継承したMyTableViewを作ります。

「UITableView#delegate: UITableViewDelegate」が「UIScrollView#delegate: 
「MyTableView#delegate: MyTableViewDelegate」と拡張したいです。

しかし普通に書くと、以下のようにエラーになってしまいます。

```
class MyTableView: UITableView {
    override var delegate: MyTableViewDelegate? // Property 'delegate' with type 'MyTableViewDelegate?' cannot override a property with type 'UITableViewDelegate?'
}

protocol MyTableViewDelegate: UITableViewDelegate {
}
```

どうすればいいでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

別の変数名を付けて、本来のデリゲートに代入するのが良いと思います。

```
class MyTableView: UITableView {
    var myDelegate: MyTableViewDelegate? {
        set(value) {
            self.delegate = value
        }
        get {
            return self.delegate as? MyTableViewDelegate
        }
    }
}
```

余談ですが、UIを非常にこだわるのではない限りは、UITableViewを継承するのはオススメしません。